# fuzzy join with partial string match

Tags: r, match, fuzzyjoin

I have a dataframe with two columns which can contain literally any character of various formats and i would like to match them.

```
library(stringr)
library(fuzzyjoin)

x <- data.frame(idX=1:3, string=c("silver", "30BEDJE202AA", "30BEDJE2027"))
y <- data.frame(idY=letters[1:3], seed=c("sliver", "30BEDJE202ABC", "30BEDJE2027BL"))
x$string = as.character(x$string)
y$seed = as.character(y$seed)

x %>% fuzzy_left_join(y, by = c(string = "seed"), match_fun = str_detect)
```

Here is the result i get when running the above code:

```
  idX       string  idY seed
1   1       silver <NA> <NA>
2   2 30BEDJE202AA <NA> <NA>
3   3  30BEDJE2027 <NA> <NA>
```

And this is what i would like to have:

```
  idX       string  idY seed
1   1       silver  a sliver
2   2 30BEDJE202AA  b 30BEDJE202ABC
3   3  30BEDJE2027  c 30BEDJE2027BL
```

Is there a way to get there?

Comment: Why should string 30BEDJE2027 match to seed 30BEDJE2027BL and not 30BEDJE202?

Comment: Thanks to both of you. Valid point Aron. I modified the original post to remove any ambiguity.

Comment: @Romain then as tifu said: `stringdist_left_join(x,y,by=c(string="seed"),max_dist=2)`

Comment: Indeed, it works well. Thanks!

Comment: (**removed old comment because of critical typo**): You could play around with the different methods in fuzzyjoin::stringdist_join(), but I doubt that will get you your results since the similarity between idX == 2 and idY == 3 seems to simply be higher than between idX == 2 and idY == 2, regardless of what method is used to calculate the distance